# How to specify sslmode in sqlalchemy (create engine) in python connection string?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

```
engine = create_engine("postgresql+psycopg2://(username):(password)@(hostname):(port)/(dbname)",connect_args={'sslmode':'true'})
```

I tried above code while using **cdk** deploy got error from aws which is :

```
[ERROR] OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) invalid sslmode value: "true"
```

Also, `connect_args={'sslmode':'require/prefer'}` is not working as :

```
FATAL:  SSL connection is required. Please specify SSL options and retry
```

Answer (score 4):

This is the right syntax:

```
engine = create_engine(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, connect_args={'sslmode': "allow"})
```

You can also change the kind of `sslmode`. For more info pls check [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/libpq-ssl.html#LIBPQ-SSL-SSLMODE-STATEMENTS).

Please be aware that your Postgresql server needs to support ssl connections if you want to be able to connect through it. For this reason you have to run it with `ssl=on` option and also specify certificates to use.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for being late to the party. For postgresql you use use the same parameters (mostly) you'd use on the command line, through a configuration variable:

```py
    SQLALCHEMY_ENGINE_OPTIONS = {
        "connect_args": dict(host=os.environ['POSTGRES_HOST'], user=os.environ['POSTGRES_USER'],
                             password=os.environ['POSTGRES_PASSWORD'], dbname=os.environ['POSTGRES_DB'],
                             sslcert="client.crt", sslkey="client.key",
                             sslrootcert="ca.crt", sslmode="verify-full", ssl_min_protocol_version="TLSv1.3")
    }
```

Whenever you create the connection, these arguments will be picked up. You might have problems generating the self-signed ssl certificate for local testing: using names on the CN will prevent this connection line to succeed with 'verify-full'. In that case, the options are to revert to just 'require', to upgrade to 'verify-ca' (ca is verified but not hostname), or to generate the certificates with 127.0.0.1 (or the corresponding ip) everywhere... and then it will succeed with verify-full.